# DataTable Server side in Codeigniter, Searching feature doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatable, codeigniter-3

So, I just started to learn Ajax and I want to apply it with DataTable Server-side. And now, I have this problem, the search feature returns an error saying 
DataTables warning: table id=mitsuha - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Controller

```
function get_ajax() 
{
    $list = $this->code->get_datatables();
    $data = array();
    $no = @$_POST['start'];
    foreach ($list as $item) {
        $no++;
        $row = array();
        $row[] = $no.".";
        $row[] = $item->code_name;
        $row[] = $item->language_name;
        $row[] = $item->difficulty_name;
        $row[] = $item->nama_user;
        $row[] = '<a href="'.base_url('code/view/'.$item->code_id).'" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
               <a href="'.base_url('code/update/'.$item->code_id).'" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>';
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    $output = array(
                "draw" => @$_POST['draw'],
                "recordsTotal" => $this->code->count_all(),
                "recordsFiltered" => $this->code->count_filtered(),
                "data" => $data,
            );
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

Model

```
var $column_order = array(null, 'code.code_name', 'language.language_name', 'user.nama_user, difficulty.difficulty_name');
var $column_search = array('code.code_name', 'language.language_name', 'user.nama_user, difficulty.difficulty_name');
var $order = array('code_id' => 'desc');

private function _get_datatables_query() {
    $this->db->select('code.*, language.language_name, user.nama_user, difficulty.difficulty_name');
    $this->db->from('code');
    $this->db->join('language', 'code.language = language.language_id');
    $this->db->join('user', 'code.contributor = user.user_id');
    $this->db->join('difficulty', 'code.difficulty = difficulty.difficulty_id', 'left');
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($this->column_search as $item) { // loop column
        if($_POST['search']['value']) { // if datatable send POST for search
            if($i===0) { // first loop
                $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND.
                $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
            } else {
                $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
            }
            if(count($this->column_search) - 1 == $i) //last loop
                $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket
        }
        $i++;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['order'])) { // here order processing
        $this->db->order_by($this->column_order[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
    }  else if(isset($this->order)) {
        $order = $this->order;
        $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
    }
}
function get_datatables() {
    $this->_get_datatables_query();
    if(@$_POST['length'] != -1)
    $this->db->limit(@$_POST['length'], @$_POST['start']);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
function count_filtered() {
    $this->_get_datatables_query();
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->num_rows();
}
function count_all() {
    $this->db->from('code');
    return $this->db->count_all_results();
}
```

and the ajax

```
<script>
$(function(){

    $('#mitsuha').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url":  "<?php echo base_url('code/get_ajax') ?>",
            "type": "POST",
        },
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                // orderable untuk mengaktifkan atau non fungsi order
                "targets":      [0, 5],
                "orderable":    false
            }
        ],
        "order": []
    });
})
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, Found out already though it seems inefficient.
So I just need to change the conditional in _get_datatables_query function in the model, the column_search foreach().

```
    <?php
foreach ($this->column_search as $item) // loop column 
{
    if($_POST['search']['value']) // if datatable send POST for search
    {

        if($i===0) // first loop
        {
            $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND.
            $this->db->like('code.code_name', $_POST['search']['value']);
            $this->db->or_like("language.language_name", $_POST['search']['value']);
            $this->db->or_like("difficulty.difficulty_name", $_POST['search']['value']);
            $this->db->or_like("user.nama_user", $_POST['search']['value']);
        }

        if(count($this->column_search) - 1 == $i) //last loop
            $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket
    }
    $i++;}
```